# How to conditionally compares values in one dataframe and match values in second dataframe if conditions are true and only returning certain columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes, 'df_orders' and 'df_birthday':

I need to return email address from 'df_birthday' by performing match on consumer_id column in 'df_orders' to id column in 'df_birthday' ONLY if certain conditions are met.

Condition 1:
consumer_id field in 'df_orders' appears ONLY once.

Condition 2: 
payment_complete field in 'df_orders' field equals '1.0'

Condition 3:
if TIME NOW is ONLY 24 hours ahead of updated_at (datetime) field in 'df_orders'.

Condition 4:
If condition 1 and 2 are true return columns 'first_name', 'last_name' and 'email_addr' from df_birthday by matching 'consumer_id' from 'df_order' to 'id' in 'df_birthday'.

To Sum up all conditions:
Need to only return email_addr, first_name, and last_name from df_birthday if consumer_id field appears once, if payment_complete field equals '1.0', and updated_at field is exactly 24hours less than time now.

Here is my code(not sure how to retrieve columns 'first_name', 'last_name' and 'email_addr' from df_birthday if conditions 1-3 are true):

```
def first_purchase():
    if df_order.groupby("consumer_id").filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1):
        return "consumer_id"
    elif df_order.loc[df_orders['payment_complete'] == 1.0]:
        return 'payment_complete'
```

Should I write another function to compare the results? I am not even sure if this needs to in a function or for loop?

Here is for loop I have been tinkering with(not right):

```
for first_purchase in df_orders:
     if df_orders.groupby("consumer_id").filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1):
         elif df_orders.loc[df_orders['payment_complete'] == 1.0]:
             else print 'fail'
```

Thank you in advance

Edit:

Sample Input:

```
df_birthday:

  first_name last_name email_addr  id
0          a         A        a@A   1
1          b         B        b@B   2
2          c         B        c@C   3

df_orders:

   consumer_id  payment_complete updated_at
0            1                 1.0 2018-01-28
1            1                 1.0 2018-01-28
2            2                 1.0 2018-01-28
3            3                 0 2018-01-28
```

Sample Output:

```
    first_name last_name email_addr     
0          b         B        b@B
```

Comment: please post sample input and expected output

Comment: added input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter a temporary copy of the orders dataframe first, and use that to filter the birthday dataframe, so only the records remain that we want to join. Then we can join the birthday dataframe back on the orders dataframe.

Working example below, hope this helps!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

df_birthday = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'A','a@A',1], 
                            ['b', 'B','b@B',2], 
                            ['c', 'B','c@C',3]], 
                           columns=["first_name", "last_name",'email_addr','id'])

df_orders = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1.1], 
                            [1, 1.0], 
                            [2, 1.0],
                            [3, 0.0]], 
                           columns=["consumer_id", "payment_complete"])
df_orders['updated_at'] = pd.to_datetime('today')  + dt.timedelta(hours=1)

# Filters:
# Only occurs once
# Has payment complete == 1
# datetime difference with timestamp less than 24 hours.
df_temp = df_orders.groupby("consumer_id").filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1)
df_temp = df_temp[np.isclose(df_temp.payment_complete,1)]
df_temp = df_temp[(dt.datetime.now()- df_temp['updated_at']).astype('timedelta64[m]')<(24*60)]

# Filter the df_birthday dataframe, and join on our df_orders
df_birthday2 = df_birthday[df_birthday.id.isin(df_temp.consumer_id)]
print(df_birthday2)

# Only necessary if you want to join
df_orders = pd.merge(df_orders, df_birthday2, how='left', left_on='consumer_id', right_on='id')
df_orders = df_orders.drop('id',axis=1)   
print(df_orders)
```

df_birthday:

```
  first_name last_name email_addr  id
0          a         A        a@A   1
1          b         B        b@B   2
2          c         B        c@C   3
```

df_orders:

```
   consumer_id  payment_complete updated_at
0            1                 1 2018-01-28 01:00:00
1            1                 1 2018-01-28 01:00:00
2            2                 1 2018-01-28 01:00:00
3            3                 0 2018-01-28 01:00:00
```

Resulting df_birthday2:

```
  first_name last_name email_addr  id
1          b         B        b@B   2
```

Resulting df_orders (if you run the last three lines):

```
   consumer_id  payment_complete updated_at          first_name last_name email_addr  
0            1                 1 2018-01-28 01:00:00        NaN       NaN        NaN   
1            1                 1 2018-01-28 01:00:00        NaN       NaN        NaN   
2            2                 1 2018-01-28 01:00:00         b         B        b@B   
3            3                 0 2018-01-28 01:00:00        NaN       NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Hi @Florian thank you for the response, I need to filter field 'payment_complete' on '1.0' rather than '1' and the dtype is float. Can I simply change '1' to '1.0'? 

Instead of filter on the existing 'df_order', how do I create a new df with ONLY 'first_name', 'last_name',and 'email_addr' where the conditions are met?  I need to be able to export only those three field in a csv.

Comment: Hi @RustyShackleford. You can check if floats are equal with `np.isclose()`. Also, to obtain only the `dataframe` with the customer information I have created a dataframe called `df_birthday2`, which contains the data you need (you can drop the id column of course with `df_birthday2.drop('id',1)`). Hope this helps!

Comment: that works last question, the 'updated_at' field is datetime stamp, and all dates are in the past. I need to compare the day for the next day not with today. I.E timestamp 2017-12-02 20:17:38  need to only show row if today date is less than 2017-12-03 20:17:38. I changed 'timedelta64[D]')<1 but it does not seem to be working. Still getting two rows in 'df_birthday2'

Comment: @RustyShackleford I modified the example slightly. `(dt.datetime.now()- df_temp['updated_at']).astype('timedelta64[m]')` now returns the difference between the timestamp and the current time in minutes. So as long as that is less than `24*60` the record is good to go ;)